# Display foreign key of a FormSet value in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I got two models:

```
class Box(models.Model): 
    ...
    material = models.ForeignKey('Material', related_name='box_materials',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Material(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In form.py I got this:

```
BoxesUpdateFormSet= inlineformset_factory(Entry, Box, form=BoxesForm, can_delete=True, extra=0)

class BoxesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Box
    fields = ['kg', 'material', 'price']
```

I want to display the Box material in the template, but {{ box.material }} displays a Select object, while I would like to display just a text instead. I've tried {{ box.material.value}}, but I only get the ID. With {{ box.material.name }} I get nothing.

What can I do to display the value of an Child Model attribute as a text?

Comment: So wish to have a read-only `material` **object** as a text in the text-box?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specified, but I've edited it. I want to display it just as a text.

Comment: I don't understand what "as a text" means. Do you mean an editable text field, or just as standard non-editable text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, below your **fields** in `forms.py` add this code:

```
from django.forms import TextInput

widgets = {
    'material': TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'})
}
```

What this code does is, it makes your **material** table object as readonly.

**Edit - Included the `textinput` import**

Complete `forms.py`

```
from django.forms import TextInput

class BoxesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields = ['kg', 'material', 'price']
        widgets = {
           'material': TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'})
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. This way it's displayed as I wanted, but it still displays the id (for example, '3'), while I should get the name, as I've overrided the __str__ function. How can I do that?

Comment: If you check in your admin panel, it will show you the name of `material`  as saved but i know it shows `material_id` in the text box. Give me sometime i'll figure it out and let you know.